# Extract multiple specific characters from string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following innerHTML in element id "word":

```
<span class="green">h</span><span class="white">e</span><span class="white">l</span><span class="green">l</span><span class="white">o</span
```

I would like to create a function (wordReverter) that removes all of the  tags, leaving in the above example, only the word "hello".
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
function wordReverter() {
  var word = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
  //var rejoinedWord = rejoined word with <span> tags removed
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = rejoinedWord;
}
```

Comment: use `innerText`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the innerText and use it as a new innerHtml like below

```js
(function wordReverter() {
  var word = document.getElementById("word").innerText;
  document.getElementById("word").innerHTML = word;
})()
```

```html
<div id="word">
<span class="green">h</span><span class="white">e</span><span class="white">l</span><span class="green">l</span><span class="white">o</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes to `.innerText`. No to that ridiculous *(and named?)* self-executing function. Actually, I even found some Browsers failing unless the self-executor is like `(function(){ }());` or `(()=>{ }());`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the containing element, you can target it and retrieve it's `textContent`, otherwise, you can select all the elements of interest and retrieve their content as below:

```js
function wordReverter() {
  let letters = document.querySelectorAll('.white,.green')
  return Array.from(letters).map(l=>l.textContent).join('')
}

console.log(wordReverter())
```

```html
<span class="green">h</span><span class="white">e</span><span class="white">l</span><span class="green">l</span><span class="white">o</span>
```